# Dynamic 2D array. Why is segmentation fault?

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic

my question is very simple. Look at this code.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int **arr = new int*[3];
    cout << "arr : " << arr << endl;   // It will display address, may be 0xffc1e...
    cout << "*arr : " << *arr << endl;    // will be just 0(zero), may be default value
    cout << "**arr : " << **arr << endl;    // it will display nothing,  and after that program terminates
    cout << "Program completed." << endl;    // This will not display because program terminated
}
```

This program terminates,  due to retrieving **arr. If we get rid of line were is **arr. Program will normal completed and will be wrote "Program completed". gdb says that this is segmentation fault. So that this code will work.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int **arr = new int*[3];
    cout << "arr : " << arr << endl;   // It will display address, may be 0xffc1e...
    cout << "*arr : " << *arr << endl;    // will be just 0(zero), may be default value
    cout << "Program completed." << endl;    // This at last will be displayed
}
```

So without line where is **arr, code works normally. Why???

Comment: The 'new' allocates an array of 3 pointers to int, but they are not set to anything. Until they are, you can read one of them, but you can't read what it's pointing to.

Comment: @TedLyngmo thank you, i have correct due to you.

Comment: What are you expecting the value of `**arr` to be? Can you convince [a rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) that you set this value at some point?

Comment: The statements printing both `*arr` and `**arr` have undefined behaviour.    `arr` is a dynamically allocated array of three uninitialised pointers, so accessing `*arr` has undefined behaviour.   Part of the process of evaluating `**arr` involves evaluating `*arr` so that also has undefined behaviour.    When behaviour is undefined, you can get lucky (or unlucky, depending on how you look at it) and the code appears to work.    The fact your second sample of code (with printing `**arr` removed) seems to work is just happenstance - the statement printing `*arr` STILL has undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Peter execuse me, why *arr in this code udefined? my program displays 0(zero) in the first and second code. I can understand that **arr is undefined, but I still find what values has declared 2d dynamic array. So why *arr which returns 0(zero)  is undefined? May be it is a default value?

Comment: @Makari21 - `new int *[3]` dynamically allocates an array of three pointers, but does not initialise those pointers.  Accessing `*arr` (or the value of any element of that array, such as `arr[0]`, `arr[1]`, or `arr[2]`) therefore gives undefined behaviour.    You're just getting lucky that - with your compiler/library, when you are running your code - that the array elements are being initialised as null pointers.   The standard doesn't require that.

Comment: @Peter thanks, now I understand almost all about this situation. I think this instance sufficiently general for most situations and this page have enough info and answers for the complete grasp.

Answer (score 1):

You've default initialised the dynamic array. It is an array of pointers. Default initialised pointers have an indeterminate value. The behaviour of reading an indeterminate value is undefined.

> Why???

Because the behaviour of the program is undefined.

Undefined behaviour means that nothing about the behaviour of the program is guaranteed. As far as the language is concerned, the program might:

- Produce output that you expect.
- Produce output that you didn't expect.
- Produce output that you want to be produced.
- Produce some output that you didn't want.
- Not produce output at all.
- Crash
- Not crash
- Behave differently on another system.
- Behave differently on the same system.
- Behave differently when you're debugging it.
- Behave differently only when you are on vacation.
- Behave differently for any reason possible.
- Behave differently for seemingly no reason at all.
- Behave the same always
- Not behave like that.
- Have any behaviour whatsoever.

Undefined behaviour is to be avoided.

Comment: Thank you, your answer so fast, wonderful. Can you advise me the thread of such behaviour, wherein i can read about this? I mean some article or manual.

Comment: @Makari21: You can read more about undefined behavior [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). In short, all it means is that if you do something you are not allowed to do, then anything can happen (go wrong), for example your program could crash due to a segmentation fault. However, it seems to me that you need to first read a proper C/C++ tutorial on how pointers work and how to use them.

Comment: @Makari21 I've added an explanation of what undefined behaviour means.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel thank you. I am newbie, and i think these answers will help other,  because, we described particular instance.

Answer (score 1):

You've allocated space for 3 `int*`, but you haven't initialized any of them, so reading them, like `*arr` does, makes your program have undefined behaviour.

Reading from the address returned by `*arr` (if any), like `**arr` does, also makes it have undefined behaviour - and often leads to a crash (if you are lucky).

You need to make the `int*`s point *at* something. Initialize the pointers. Also note that for every `new` you need exactly one `delete` and for every `new[]` you need exactly one `delete[]`.

Some examples:

```
int main() {
    int** arr = new int*[3];

    arr[0] = new int[5];  // an array of 5 int
    arr[1] = new int[10]; // 10...
    arr[2] = new int[20]; // 20...

    // use arr

    // cleanup
    delete[] arr[2];
    delete[] arr[1];
    delete[] arr[0];

    delete[] arr;
}
```

Note that the memory allocated is still not initialized so you should not be reading from it before you've stored data in it.

The cleanup may easily be forgotten or skipped if anything happens (like an exception). For that purpose, there are smart pointers. They may look awkward at first, but will save you a world of trouble.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
int main() {
    std::unique_ptr<std::unique_ptr<int[]>[]> arr = 
                                         std::make_unique<std::unique_ptr<int[]>[]>(3);

    arr[0] = std::make_unique<int[]>(5);
    arr[1] = std::make_unique<int[]>(10);
    arr[2] = std::make_unique<int[]>(20);

    // using arr
    std::cout << arr[0][4] << "\n";  // Using make_unique also default initialized the 
    std::cout << arr[1][9] << "\n";  // elements in the arrays, so reading from them is 
    std::cout << arr[2][19] << "\n"; // fine.

} // all arrays held by smart pointers are automatically deleted when arr
  // goes out of scope
```

Comment: Thank you very much. My grasp have become more complete.